# Is it possible to sign an unsigned xap in Windows Phone 8 programatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Before distributing a company app or a Company Hub app, you must sign the XAP with the enterprise certificate that was obtained from Symantec. Is it possible to sign a company app programatically ?